# How to understand composition of functions with multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

Such as:

```
var foo = function (a, b) { return a + b; };
var bar = function (a, b) { return a * b; };

var fn = _.compose([foo, bar]);
```

How to understand the `fn`?

Comment: I don't think you can compose those two functions like that.

Answer (score 6):

This will not work.

First off, `_.compose()` doesn't take an array.  It takes a list of functions as separate arguments as in:

```
var fn = _.compose(foo, bar);
```

Then, even with it done that way, with underscore's `_.compose()`, each successive function is passed the return result of the previous function.  Since both your functions require two arguments and return one, this will not work.

If you fix your code to pass the arguments properly to `_.compose()`, then you'd have this:

```
var foo = function (a, b) { return a + b; };
var bar = function (a, b) { return a * b; };

var fn = _.compose(foo, bar);
```

and if you then use `fn` like this:

```
fn(2, 5);
```

it will try to execute:

```
foo(bar(2, 5));
```

Breaking this apart, `bar(2, 5)` will return `10`, so you would then have the result of calling `foo(10)`, but that generates `NaN` because the second argument to `foo()` is `undefined`.

`_.compose` is designed for functions beyond the last one in the list that operate on a single argument that is the return value of the prior function in the list.

Actual implementation showing that it returns `NaN`: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xhbcdh9k/

Comment: here's a little helper function for when you want to pass in the rest params as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/compound-util

Answer (score 0):

The `compose` function takes multiple functions and returns a single function. So you would call it as such: `var fn = compose(foo, bar);`

You can think of `fn` as nothing more than the result of calling `bar` then `foo`. e.g. `bar(foo());`

Your functions won't compose, since `foo` expects 2 parameters `foo(a, b)`, but `bar` returns 1 value.

[I wrote about compose, maybe it can help you understand it better.](http://waltfy.net/2015/04/07/writing-compose.html)

Answer (score 0):

[shameless self-promotion]

I wrote a little helper function which behaves like compose, but also passes the rest params:

```
const compound = (...fns) => (...args) =>
  fns
    .reverse()
    .reduce((result, fn) => fn(...[result, ...args.slice(1)]), args[0])
```

https://github.com/pdme/compound